# Palindrome numbers - Project Euler Problem 4

Tags: c, programming-challenge, palindrome

[Project Euler Problem #4: Largest palindrome product](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4):

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

I got the correct answer for the problem, but I want to know if my coding style is good or bad for this solution.
I need to know how I can improve my coding, if it is bad and write this in a more general way.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 999
#define START 100

int main()
{
   int i,j,current,n,prev = 0;
for(i = START;i<=MAX;i++)
{
    for(j=START;j<=MAX;j++)
    {
        current = j * i;
        if(current > prev)  /*check the current value so that if it is less need not go further*/
        {
            n = palindrome(current);
            if (n == 1)
            {
                printf("The palindrome number is : %d\n",current);
                prev = current;  // previous value is updated if this the best possible value.
            }
        }
    }
}
}

int palindrome(int num)
{
int a[6],temp;
temp = num;
/*We need a array to store each element*/
a[5] = temp % 10;       
a[4] = (temp/10) %10;
a[3] = (temp/100) %10;
a[2] = (temp/1000) %10;
a[1] = (temp/10000) %10;
if(temp/100000 == 0)
{
    a[0] = 0;
    if(a[1] == a[5] && a[2] == a[4])
        return 1;
}
else
{
    a[0] = (temp/100000) %10;
    if(a[0] == a[5] && a[1] == a[4] && a[2] == a[3])
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: [Please embed a short summary of the challenge in your question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/should-programming-challenge-questions-require-a-summary-of-the-challenge)

Comment: @outoftime: The way I understand it, reformatting the code in questions asked about is explicitly something we don't do, as it renders part of possible reviews moot.

Comment: @outoftime, It's probably easier to post the formatting changes as answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you are only interested in the biggest number, so *why* do you start from the bottom??
   Correcting that allows you to dispense with an explicit lower boundary, a dynamic boundary can be computed depending on current-best result.
2. Why don't you read the upper boundary from the command-line?
3. Proper indentation is a very valuable help in quickly and accurately reading source-code, as well as ferreting out errors.
   In your case, the one level of indentation missing through much of your code *might* be an artifact of sloppy posting here. Whether or not it is, *don't do that*.
4. You are depending on implicit definition of `palindrome`. Don't do that, reverse their positions.
5. An `int` only has a guaranteed range of -32767 to 32767. Use a `long` (or `unsigned long`), that has the proper range without depending on implementation-dependent behaviour.
6. Why do you use an array and all that paraphernalia to check for being a palindrome, simply reversing is easy:

   ```
   unsigned long reverse(unsigned long in) {
       unsigned long r = 0;
       for(; in; in /= 10)
           r = r * 10 + in % 10;
       return r;
   }
   ```

Final program ([on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfb039f3e1e54f8)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int is_palindrome(const unsigned long in) {
    unsigned long r = 0;
    for(unsigned long x = in; x; x /= 10)
        r = r * 10 + x % 10;
    return r == in;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned long max = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], 0, 10) : 0;
    if(!max || max > 9999)
        max = 999;
    unsigned long _a = 0, _b = 0, _m = 0; // best yet
    for(unsigned long a = max, a_min = 1; a >= a_min; --a)
        for(unsigned long b = max, b_min = _m / a + 1; b >= b_min; --b)
            if(is_palindrome(a*b)) {
                _a = a, _b = b, _m = a*b, a_min = _m / max + 1;
                break;
            }
    printf("Biggest palindrome-number which is product of two natural numbers"
        " no bigger than %lu: %lu = %lu * %lu\n", max, _m, _a, _b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. I didn't think the idea of counting from the bottom. It will save lot of computing time thanks for the awesome info.

Comment: Just be aware that while I can break the inner loop on finding a palindrome, I still cannot break the outer loop, only raise it's lower limit.

Comment: Suggest `if(!max || max > 9999)` --> `if(max > 999)`  (Change limit to 999).

Comment: @chux: I set the limit to 9999 because all 4-digit-numbers can be squared and reversed in a `long`, but not all 5-digit-numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your palindrome detecting function a little bit more general, so that it can handle any `int`, easily:

```
/* Range of int is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 */
#define MAX_INT_DIGITS 10

int is_palindrome(int num)
{
    int idx;
    int count = 0;
    int digits[MAX_INT_DIGITS];

    while (num) {
        digits[count] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        ++count;
    }

    for (idx = 0; idx < count / 2; ++idx) {
        if (digits[idx] != digits[count - idx]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Notice especially how the magic number `10` (which would be `6` in your code), gets named for the code reader's benefit.

Also, since you are looking for the largest possible value, it is better to iterate from large to small values, and break out of loops early:

```
#define MAX_3_DIGIT 999
#define MIN_3_DIGIT 100

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int largest_palindrome = 0;

    for (i = MAX_3_DIGIT; i >= MIN_3_DIGIT; --i) {
        if (MAX_3_DIGIT * i <= largest_palindrome) {
            break;
        }
        for (j = MAX_3_DIGIT; j >= MIN_3_DIGIT; --j) {
            int value = i * j;

            if (value <= largest_palindrome) {
                break;
            }
            if (is_palindrome(value)) {
                largest_palindrome = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return largest_palindrome;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, your range of `int` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to check the digit palindrome without using array, but reverse the digit by using `int` instead

```
int isPalindrome(int n) {
    int np = 0;
    for(int r = n; r > 0; r /= 10) {
       np *= 10;
       np += r % 10; 
    }
    return n == np;
}
```

It is also better run from `MAX` down to `START`, because you can break immediately when you find first palindrome.

Comment: Breaking on finding the first palindrome is wrong. Still, the loop can be optimized severely by dynamically raising the lower bound when finding a new current-best solution.